# Intuitive understanding of relationship between inner product and norm

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products

For any complex inner product space, for two arbitrary elements $x,y$, we have the following relationship:

$$
\langle x,y \rangle = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \| x + e^{it}y \|^2 e^{it} dt
$$

This is straight forward to prove but I am wondering how to interpret this result, or how to think about it intuitively.

Comment: We also have it for the real case: $\langle x, y\rangle =\frac{\Vert x+y\Vert^2\, -\, \Vert x-y\Vert^2}2$.